# UITextField.enabled to Yes or No according to UISwitch.on

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uiswitch

I'd like to make `textField.enabled` turn on and off.
But `textField` is not editable regardless of `switch.on`.
How do I fix it?

```
UISwitch* switch = [[UISwitch alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 293, 60, 25)];
[self.view addSubview:switch];

UITextField* textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 293, 100, 30)];
textField.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:textField];

if (switch.on == YES) {
    textField.enabled = YES;
} else {
    textField.enabled = NO;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What methods are these code fragments inside of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a target to the `UISwitch`

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UISwitch* switch = [[UISwitch alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140, 293, 60, 25)];
    [switch addTarget:self action:@selector(didChangeSwitch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.view addSubview:switch];

    UITextField* textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 293, 100, 30)];
    textField.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:textField];
    self.textField = textField;

}

-(void)didChangeSwitch:(UISwitch *)sender
{ 
    self.textField.enabled = switch.on;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By the way, You can replace

```
if (switch.on == YES) {
    textField.enabled = YES;
} else {
    textField.enabled = NO;
}
```

with

```
textField.enabled=switch.on;
```

---

Another way is to create timer:

```
NSTimer *timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1
    target:self selector:@selector(yourSelector:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Declare selector:

```
-(void)yourSelector:(NSTimer*)timer
{
textField.enabled=switch.on
}
```

Comment: What on earth is the timer for?!

Answer (score 0):

You need to listen when the switch is changed:

```
[switch addTarget:self action:@selector(switched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Then:

```
- (void)switched:(UISwitch *)switch {
    if (switch.on == YES) {
        textField.enabled = YES;
    } else {
        textField.enabled = NO;
    }
}
```

or more simply:

```
- (void)switched:(UISwitch *)switch {
    textField.enabled = switch.on;
}
```